# How to use R to convert character from markdown to LaTeX

Tags: r, text, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I have a variable, `x`, which is a character formatted using markdown:

```
x <- "Here is some _great_ text in a **variable** and some blank spaces ____."
```

I want to convert it to Tex so that it looks like this

```
y <- some_library::md2tex(x)
y
```

```
[1] "Here is some \textit{great} text in a \textbf{variable} and some blank spaces \_\_\_\_."
```

Is there an R function that achieves this? The backslashes themselves might need to be escaped, but you get the idea. I'm certain this exists as it's easy to convert an from `.Rmd` to a .pdf, but I'd prefer not to create and write an intermediate `.tex` file since this will need to be repeated a lot.

I've dug around the vignettes, documentation, and source code for both `knitr` and `RMarkdown` but I can't find what I'm looking for.

**EDIT**

So I found `knitr::pandoc` which is almost there but requires input and output files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write your string to a temp file, and convert that.  I recommend using `rmarkdown::render` instead of `knitr::pandoc`; they both call `pandoc`, but the former sets all the options for you:

```
x <- "Here is some _great_ text in a **variable** and some blank spaces ____."
infile <- tempfile(fileext=".md")
writeLines(x, infile)
outfile <- rmarkdown::render(infile, rmarkdown::latex_fragment(), quiet = TRUE)
readLines(outfile)
```

This produces the following output:

```
[1] "Here is some \\emph{great} text in a \\textbf{variable} and some blank"
[2] "spaces \\_\\_\\_\\_."
```

For neatness, you could remove the two temp files at the end:

```
unlink(c(infile, outfile))
```

Comment: Yeah i think this is what I have to do. Is there a recommended place for storing  temporary files with R? Or is the current working directory sufficient?

Comment: Use `tempfile()`.  The cwd might stomp on something important.

Comment: Oh duh. I see that now. Thanks.

Comment: So it looks like `rmarkdown::render` breaks lines at 72 characters (or something like that). So you can do `y <- readLines(outfile)` and `stringr::str_c(y, collapse = " ")` if this isn't desirable.

Answer (score 4):

There is a cleaner and simpler solution for this using the commonmark package:

```
commonmark::markdown_latex("Here is some _great_ text in a **variable** and some blank spaces ____.")
```